# Pandas: filter dataframe by multiple conditions with column containing nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Connected to:
[Pandas: add column with index of matching row from other dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59154836/pandas-add-column-with-index-of-matching-row-from-other-dataframe)

Matching multiple columns with corresponding columns from 2nd dataframe, and returning index of the matching row from the 2nd dataframe.

```
df1['new_column'] =  df1.apply(lambda x: df2[(df2.col1 == x.col1)
                                           & (df2.col2 == x.col2)
                                           & (df2.col3 == x.col3)
                                           & (df2.col4 == x.col4)
                                           & (df2.col5 == x.col5)].index[0], axis=1)
```

Code above works like a charm... unless one of the columns can contain nan values, since nan != nan.
In other words, even if **col1:col4** in **df1** matches **df2** and **col5** in both **df1** and **df2** is **nan** it fails to match it returning empty index object.
I need it to return True if col1:col5 match no matter if they contain values or nan.

Anyone knows solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

One workaround here is to simply use `fillna` to replace all `na` values with something like a `'NaN'` string.

Simply use:

```
df1 = df1.fillna('NaN')
df2 = df2.fillna('NaN')
```

Then use your existing code.

Comment: It crossed my mind. Replace nan, process new column, restore nan, will go with it if there is no more elegant solution.

Comment: Elegance is a false god! If an elegant solution requires you learning two new functions, a practical workaround in 4 lines is better imo :P